# how to get Name of the node in XML

Tags: c#, xml

```
<Tables>
  <Table name="Test">
    <tablename>TestTable</tablename>
    <refTable>NULL</refTable>
    <refTableIDColumn>NULL</refTableIDColumn>
  </Table>
</Tables>
```

Above is my XML input. I am able to extract nodes by Table name using below code

```
XmlNodeList companyList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Table");
```

I want the name which is given to `Table` node. For eg here I want the Text as `"Test"`. How do I get that. Please help.

Comment: What you call "name" is really the _attribute_ whose name is "name".  Use whatever methods C# has for accessing the _attributes_ of a tag.

Comment: your `Tables` tag is not closed correctly, please edit the xml in question

Answer (score 1):

The `XmlNodeList` can be filtered/queried with [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp). In your case, you want to look for the `name` attribute of a `Table` which would like this for example:

```
var tableNames = doc.SelectNodes("//Table/@name");
```

You result will be a collection of XmlAttributes, the actual name can be retrieved with the `InnerText` property.

[See it in action on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/F1GfVh)

btw: your last xml-tag is missing a `/`

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your xml file in `C` drive named `test.xml` then you can get the name using this code

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\test.xml");

XElement root = xDoc.Element("Tables");    // select root
XElement elm1 = root.Element("Table");    // get elm1 == null
string name = elm1.Attribute("name").Value;
```